# Searching for a command line tagging tool for mp3 and ogg that supports pictures

Tags: software-rec, images, mp3, ogg, vorbis

I am searching a command-line tagging tool that supports ogg- and mp3-tagging and allows to add a picture to the tags.

Currently I use [`lltag`](http://home.gna.org/lltag/) but that does not support pictures. [`dagger`](http://freewarepoint.de/dagger/) is the tool I use before but it is lacking picture support as well.

Comment: Do you really want a picture inside the mp3/ogg file? Is that even supported by the file format (the id3 tag)?

Comment: Yes it is supported. See your podcast of choice, a graphical tool to do that would be EasyTAG - http://easytag.sourceforge.net/

Comment: <3 easytag! but unfortunately I know of no other tool that can do it...

Comment: For mp3, the [mutagen](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/mutagen) python library supports APIC (example: http://www.mydigitallife.co.za/index.php?option=com_myblog&show=1046123&Itemid=29). I don't know of a command line tool that does; if you know python you could write a simple wrapper.

Answer (score 8):

For MP3, try [eyeD3](http://eyed3.nicfit.net/), found in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1340593/linux-library-to-write-id3v2-data-and-cover-art/1364820#1364820) SO answer.

```
  --add-image=IMG_PATH:TYPE[:DESCRIPTION]
                      Add an image to the tag.  The description and type
                      optional, but when used, both ':' delimiters must be
                      present.  The type MUST be an string that corresponds
                      to one given with --list-image-types. If the IMG_PATH
                      value is empty the APIC frame with TYPE is removed.
```

For Ogg, there's [vorbiscomment](http://downloads.xiph.org/releases/vorbis/vorbis-tools-1.2.0.tar.gz). It doesn't support loading image files out of the box, but a cover art tag in Vorbis is just an image file encoded in base64, stored in the COVERART tag and its mimetype in COVERARTMIME - something like

```
coverart=$(base64 $jpegfile)
vorbiscomment -a -t 'COVERART=$coverart' -t 'COVERARTMIME=image/jpeg' $infile $outfile
```

Comment: I will give it a try. Thanks a lot. But it seems to lack support for ogg-files.

Comment: You're right. I've updated the answer, but the ogg solution isn't as clean.

Comment: Maybe, I have to write something for myself. Thanks for your support.

Comment: Please optimize the images before inserting them into tags, especially if you're inserting them into every file. I even wrote [a script](http://pastebin.com/1GvcifYa) to help with this process. Just trying to help. :-)

Comment: Good answer, though line breaks in the base64 encoding do not work, should be `coverart=$(base64 -w 0 $jpegfile)`. Tested and image shows up in VLC media player!

Answer (score 0):

[**tageditor**](https://github.com/Martchus/tageditor) supports a wide variety of **formats**, and has both a **GUI** and **CLI** interface.

```
tageditor set \
    album="${album}" \
    artist="${artist}" \
    title="${title}" \
    genre="${genre}" \
    --files "${file}"
```

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/quodlibet/mutagen provides `mid3v2`. It is slower than classic `id3v2` but runs absolutely reliable.

Comment: mutagens mid3* commands corrupt ogg files. absolutely reliably.