# Seeking command-line example for adding images to MP3 files

Tags: shell, ubuntu, command-line, mp3

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Searching for a command line tagging tool for mp3 and ogg that supports pictures](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4595/searching-for-a-command-line-tagging-tool-for-mp3-and-ogg-that-supports-pictures)

Anyone have a command-line example illustrating how to properly embed an image (for instance, cover art) in an mp3 file?

I use Ubuntu, but I'm hoping the answer will run on any POSIX-compatible system, preferably in the Bash shell.

Comment: This Unix-&-Linux question/anser may help ..[Searching for a command line tagging tool for mp3 and ogg that supports pictures](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4595/searching-for-a-command-line-tagging-tool-for-mp3-and-ogg-that-supports-pictures)

Comment: Looks like it's the very same question some months later.

Comment: Indeed, thanks! I missed the dupe in searches I did before posting.